# Allowing a vim mapping to forward command to enclosing application (e.g. tmux)

Tags: vim, tmux

I have a mapping (say, ctrl-m) which, in some circumstances (e.g., multiple buffers open), I want vim to follow. In other instances, I want vim to ignore it. This can be encoded into a function relatively easily.

The next constraint is that if I decide to ignore the key command, I want the enclosing application to process it. For example, ctrl-m would cascade out to the enclosing tmux session.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: A large and crucial part of the question is missing: your function.

Comment: not crucial, irrelevant. clearly answer below shows understanding of the concept

Answer (score 1):

Once keystrokes have been received and consumed by Vim, they are gone and done with from the perspective of tmux. Your Vim function, when it realizes that the received keys should rather do an action in tmux, will have to somehow communicate this back to tmux (but probably not by emitting keystrokes, rather through invoking tmux in a way that connects to the existing instance, like `vim --remove-send`; I know little about tmux, but there are Vim plugins that integrate with tmux and may do something like that).

In general, I would try to avoid such key overloads across applications, and instead settle for separate key combinations.